# Monitoring PhD positions in TCS

Tags: soft-question, career

Are there any ways of getting to know about new PhD positions in TCS other then just looking trough ubniversity/research groups web sites?

Maybe people from different branches (type theory, verification, complexity, etc.) can name some specialized mailing-lists where PhD positions announcements are quite usual.

PS In my university we haven't got huge TCS research and we always have smart students “at hand” which are good candidates for sending for PhD positions, but in order to make this process more effective it would be nice to have some sources of new positions opening.

Answer (score 10):

PhD positions in TCS and Discrete Math are sometimes announced on [TheoryNet](https://listserv.nodak.edu/archives/theorynt.html) and [DMANET](http://www.zaik.de/AFS/publications/dmanet/). These are mailing lists to circulate announcements and questions regarding conferences, workshops, seminars, books and jobs in these areas.

Answer (score 8):

This is a somewhat Euro-centric issue. In the US, there aren't such things as "Ph.D positions". People merely apply to grad school where theory folks are.

Comment: Is this really an *answer* to the question?

Comment: @Jukka, actually I was thinking about posting something similar. Announcing PhD positions is very uncommon in US *and Canada*. North American universities admit PhD students every year. Whether a particular professor is looking to get new students is a different story.

Answer (score 2):

For type theory, the TYPES/announce mailing list appears to be the place where these are announced.  There's also the LOGIC mailing list where theoretical jobs are announced in the German speaking world.

The Haskell subreddit at Reddit.com also has some announcements from time to time related to functional programming and type theory.

The best thing to do is probably to subscribe to a big university theory group's announcement mailing list.  Announcements get CC'd to those as a matter of course.